# Python program prints one blank line after reading a text file

Tags: python

I'm doing some simple python exercises in which the target is to simply read a text file and then print it. But my program prints one extra blank line.

Text file is model.txt, which has 3 text rows and 1 blank row, is displayed here

```
First row
Second row
This is the third row
```

My program is

```py
file1=open("model.txt","r")
while True:
    row=file1.readline()
    print(row[:-1])
    if row=="":
        break
file1.close()
```

Now the wanted print result is:

```
First row
Second row
This is the third row
```

But instead there is one extra blank line after the print:

```
First row
Second row
This is the third row
```

There is a way to remove that one blank line but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: `readline()` includes the newline at the end.  So the blank line isn't `""`, it is `"\n"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your loop doesn't `break` soon enough. Read your file like this instead:

```
with open('model.txt', 'r') as file1:
  for line in file1.readlines():
      trimmed_line = line.rstrip()
      if trimmed_line: # Don't print blank lines
          print(trimmed_line)
```

The `with` statement will handle automatically closing the file and the `rstrip()` removes the `\n` and spaces at the end of the sentence.

Comment: This actually removes the last letter of the last line when I tried it with python3. so doing line.replace("\n","") is probably better ?

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  The input file _actually contains a blank line_ at the end, which he doesn't want to print.

Comment: @painor I just copied it from his question, I didn't know the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

By default `print()` adds LF to each line printed, so if your `print(row[:-1])` is empty (`row[:-1]` is empty string) then you still will get that behavior. The workaround would be to replace

```
print(row[:-1])
```

with

```
val = row[:-1]
if val: 
    print(val)
```

so empty value is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("model.txt", "r") 
for line in file: 
   print(line, end='')
```

Because the newline is read, it can also print printed with line, no need for line[:-1]

The 'end' option is left here as I need to read this page, filter out some python2 stuff, and then try to understand what that does do ;)
[How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)